# Combinatorial argument for divisibility

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A$ be a set of $11$ positive integers such that for all $x \in A$ we have $20 \nmid x$. Prove that there are two integers $a, b \in A$ such that $20|(a+b)$ or $20|(a-b)$.

Any ideas, how to approach this problem? I have to solve it in a combinatorial way.

Comment: i have confusions about the mathematical interpretation of the word 'or'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in A$, then $x\equiv \{\pm 1, \pm 2,\ldots, \pm 9, 10\}\pmod{20}$.

If $\exists a,b\in A$ such that $a\equiv b\pmod{20}$, then we're done. If not, then all elements of $A$ are incongruent mod $20$.

Then by Pigeonhole principle $\exists c,d\in A$ such that $c\equiv k,\, d\equiv -k\pmod{20}$, where $k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}\pmod{20}$.

Comment: Why do we have $x\equiv \{\pm 1, \pm 2,\ldots, \pm 9, 10\}\pmod{20}$? Shouldn't it be $x\equiv\{1,2...19\}$, cause we have all positive numbers in the set, and when something doesn't divide $20$, the remainder is between $1$ and $19$.

Comment: @portal $11\equiv -9,\, 12\equiv -8,\ldots, 19\equiv -1\pmod{20}$. Nothing says they must be positive. It's often useful to change positive equivalences to negative, e.g. $20^k\equiv (-1)^k\equiv \begin{cases}1,\, \text{k is even}\\-1,\, \text{k is odd}\end{cases}\pmod{21}$.

Comment: Because the first part of the problem says "Let $A$ be a set of $11$ positive integers". And I thought that those negative numbers belonged to the $A$, but they are just the remainders of the division.

Comment: @portal $14$ is a positive integer, and we still have $14\equiv -6\pmod{20}$. It's just the equivalence class it belongs to mod $20$.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. But, as I said because $A$ consists of $11$ elements, ($|A| = 11$), and all the numbers are positive numbers, according to the problem definition, I was confused a bit, but now I see that the negative numbers are just remainders, as you say equivalence classes.

Comment: I also understood the proof until the part "If not, then all elements of $A$ are incongruent mod $20$." Can you explain a bit, the part where you apply the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @portal All $11$ positive integers belong to different equivalence classes mod $20$. Worst case: we let $10$ of the numbers in $A$ be $1,2,3,\ldots, 9,10\pmod{20}$ in some order, and we still have one more number, which must belong to $\{-1,-2,-3,\ldots,-9\}\pmod{20}$, let it be $-k$, where $k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}\pmod{20}$. Then $k,-k\in A$. In any case we must have $k,-k\in A$ for some $k$, where $k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}\pmod{20}$.

Comment: @portal I can clarify more if you want. It's simply that by Pigeonhole Principle we must have either $\pm 1\in A$ or $\pm 2\in A$ or $\ldots$ or $\pm 9\in A$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: I got it, thanks!